# Php Fatal Error Class not found

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I am trying to debug an issue with a php website that was working and for some reason stopped. When I try to access the website via http it does not work so I check the server logs in Linux and this is what I get:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'HomePageBanner' not found
```

The beginning of the file has code

```
<?php 
require_once 'config.php';
include "checkiflogin.php";
$condition = "";
$objDreamVacationGallery = new HomePageBanner();
$data = $objDreamVacationGallery->selectAllRecords($condition, $sort_field, $sort_order, $start, $limit);
?>
```

The index.php is stored in the root directory and the HomePageBanner is stored in root/classes. The code for HomePageBanner looks something like

```
<?php
    class HomePageBanner extends DataBase
    {
        public $db_table = 'tblxxx';
        public $data = '';


        public function __construct($data=''){ /* VALUE ASSIGNMENT */
            parent::__construct();
            if($data!=''){
                $this->data = $data;
            }                               
        }

        public function __destruct(){
            parent::__destruct();
        }
```

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Hey man! provide screen shot of your project hierarchy!

Comment: Thanks but the answer is below. That worked for me require_once('classes/HomePageBanner.php');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to require_once homepagebanner class first as below

```
require_once('classes/HomePageBanner.php');
```

and as i seen in comments you are using linux make sure `classes` and `HomePageBanner` in code are in the same case as in the your directory `/var/www/html`

Comment: Would I use require_once 'HomePageBanner.php' or require_once 'classes\HomePageBanner.php'?

Comment: require_once 'classes\HomePageBanner.php'

Comment: `require_once 'path-to-file-that-contains-HomePageBanner-class.php'`

Comment: I get error:PHP Warning:  require_once(classes\\HomePageBanner.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 4
[Thu May 10 04:14:47.088699 2018] [:error] [pid 8264] [client PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'classes\\HomePageBanner.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear7:/usr/share/php7') in

Comment: require_once 'config.php';
include "checkifuserlogin.php";
require_once 'classes\HomePageBanner.php';

Comment: You are using Linux make sure class name is Same as filename also the directory name it is case sensitive

Comment: I just changed it from require_once 'classes\HomePageBanner.php';  to require_once('classes/HomePageBanner.php'); and that worked

Comment: Issue was not related to require_once() Or require_once as i think it is related to slash you were using backward slash in linux that will work on windows but not in linux